# How can I get devise to go to use one page as root if the user is logging in but another when they are logging out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, logout, splash-screen

I'm working on a Rails 3 application that uses devise for user authentication. I would like the user to only see the splash/signup page when they first visit the site but be sent to the login page if they log out or time out, as follows:

1. Splash page

   - Click on login link
2. Login page

   - Supply proper login credentials
3. User's dashboard

   - Click on logout link or user times out
4. Login page (not splash page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in the devise wiki: [How To: Change the redirect path after destroying a session i.e. signing out](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out)